# Can't specify alternate login for remote share

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, login

This is hopefully a simple question. I'm trying to connect to a remote share from Windows 7. The first time I went to connect, I accidentally specified the wrong username. Now, whenever I try to connect to that share, it won't let me specify another username. There is only one tile in the authentication dialog and it's pre-filled with the username I entered incorrectly. A reboot has not fixed the problem.

Note that this only seems to affect Windows Explorer. I can connect properly using NET USE on the command line, where I can specify the username explicitly as a command line parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go into the "Credentials Manager" for Windows credentials.

This is found in Control Panel under User Accounts and "Manage Your Credentials".

In there you should find a reference to the resource. Simply delete the credential and Windows will re-prompt.

Comment: That did the trick.